# Drupal 7 Form API - Select element shows some empty options after migration

Tags: php, drupal, drop-down-menu

I have migrated and installed the development environment of our company in my PC. The installation was exactly the same my partner has on his machine ( IIS with exact configuration, same php version with exact php.ini,  exact version of MariaDB, etc...) and both PC's are running with Windows 7 64bit.

But there's a problem that occurs only in my PC when trying to show a list of elements in a select.

The problem is that the select element in our custom forms (with Form API) show some blank optios. Using `print_r()` before returning the `$form` element in the `hook_form` I can see that the array contains all the indexes and the values correctly.

Here is a capture of what is happening:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after days of investigating the issue, I was able to find that the charset of the database was in latin1 and not in utf8 and that was breaking some strings that have spanish accents, so reinstalling mariadb server and checking the option of the default server charset to utf8 resolved the issue.